# python - assert complex almost equal

Tags: python, numpy, unit-testing, complex-numbers

I am aware that there is `numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal`, but that only works for float and not complex. With that said, I can actually declare my own function that does this:

```py
def assert_complex_almost_equal(complex_number, ground_truth, **kwargs):
    assert numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal(complex_number.real, ground_truth.real, **kwargs)
    and numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal(complex_number.imag, ground_truth.imag, **kwargs)
```

I'd just like to confirm if there is no built-in or `numpy` function that does this in the current version?

In case needed I use `pytest` for unit testing.

Comment: `np.allclose` works with complex.  Roughly it does `np.abs(arr1-arr2)` and checks the relative and absolute max.  The `abs` reduces the differences to real.   There is also an `assert_allclose`.

Comment: The code for `assert_almost_equal` shows that it does explicitly handle the `complex` case, separately testing the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: @hpaulj You're right! Actually, the one I tried was `np.assert_approx_equal` which doesn't work for `complex`, thought that `assert_almost_equal` will behave the same. Another thing that I found just now when browsing on `pytest`, there's actually `pytest.approx`, which works similarly for assertion.

Comment: I think you'll find that SO answers almost always use `allclose`, especially if they copy-n-paste interactive code.

Comment: @hpaulj right! Is there any obvious difference in `allclose` vs `almost_equal` though?